# BIOS update validation?

Tags: bios

I have downloaded a BIOS update for the Shuttle XH61. In the description field on the [download page](http://global.shuttle.com/products/productsDownload?productId=1567&panelId=1) it says "Checksum : BC33h".

I want to confirm that the BIOS update is valid, but I can't find out what kind of checksum it is. It's not CRC, MD5, SHA or any other hash that I know of.

Any suggestions on what type of checksum it is, so I can use the correct application to confirm the update?

Comment: Perhaps some sort of custom checksum for the updater?

Comment: You sure it's not some variant of `CRC-16`? Remember the `h` indicates that it's a hexadecimal value, and is not actually a part of the checksum value.

Comment: Like @Karan hinted, could it be that the BIOS upgrade procedure will display the checksum before confirming to go ahead with the upgrade?

Comment: @user226708  - Verification is normally verified by the software that is used to update the BIOS itself.  If it doesn't report a problem then that verification process was sucessful.